# Trying to create a new file by copying data of a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to create a new csv file in a directory.

I want to store the data of a variable inside that csv file:

```
  handleRequest(req, res) {
    var svcReq = req.body.svcReq;
    var csvRecData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log("DATA WE ARE GETIING IS:  " + csvRecData);
    if (svcReq == 'invDetails') {
        var checking = fs.writeFile('../i1/csvData/myCsvFile.csv', csvRecData, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Saved! got the file");
            console.log("Checking csvData:" + checking);
        });
    }
}
```

I don't see any errors in the console or terminal but the file is not generated. What is  my issue?

Answer (score 1):

The path in **writeFile** should be pointed correctly..you cannot simply use "../il/csv" from your current file.First check your current directory using **path**.
1)Install path npm module
2)

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
console.log(path.join(__dirname))
fs.writeFile((path.join(__dirname)+"/test123.csv"), "Sally Whittaker,2018,McCarren House,312,3.75!", function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know

Comment: why don't you just `path.join(__dirname, 'test.csv')`? If you use path, no need to `+` strings

Comment: we can use that way too.i just gave an instance on how it works.Both will work